# why don't we deference char pointer array twice?

Tags: c

For eg, let us say I have a `char *arry[] ={"Hi","Hello"}`. So the base address of "Hi" (assume 100) will be stored in `arry[0]`. So to access Hi why don't we write `**arry`. As 'arry' will give base address of that array when we dereference it *arry we will get 100 and when we again dereference 100 we will get "H". In short we need to write `**arry`. Then why do we write `*arry`? When I use `**arry` it gives me error saying 'error: expected identifier before '*' token'.

Comment: Because strings are (`const`) `char *`, not just `char`. Thus `**arry` would be `'H'`.

Comment: "When I use **arry it gives me error saying 'error: expected identifier before '*' token'." For this you will have to show the code that is generating the error

Comment: It doesn't print 'H'. It gives an error saying 'error: expected identifier before '*' token

Comment: you have 2 questions here. Why not deref twice? Why do I get this compile error when trying to deref twice?. The first is answered by the first comment, the second will be answered when you should you actual code

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
char *arry[];
```

you are declaring an *array of pointers to characters*.  `arry` is an array, and each element of it is a pointer, which can point to a `char`.

If you use two indirection operators `**`, you strip off two levels of indirection.  That's fine, but what you end up with is a value of type `char`, the base type of the array.  A `char` is not a string.

But this works just fine

```
printf("%c\n", **arry);
```

It prints the first character of the first string in the array, or `'H'`.

The reason it didn't work when you tried to use `**` and then print a *string* is that, as I said, a string is not a character.  A string in C in an *array of characters*.  Or, a string can be conveniently accessed by using a pointer to `char`, pointing at the first character of the string.

So if you want to print strings, you only want to strip off one level of indirection, not two.  You want at most one `*`.  Since strings are conveniently accessed via pointers to `char`, when you use `%s` in `printf`, what it wants is a pointer to `char`.  So to print strings, you want either

```
printf("%s\n", *arry);
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", arry[0]);
```